# How to display text as new line left aligned after-an-image is over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with starting with the new beginning line after text is passed by Image.

I just wrote many sentences in the `<p>` tag in the portfolio-description part and all these texts are appeared in that part not starting with the new beginning line under image if the last line of text is passed by Image.

Here is the alignment issue https://ibb.co/825KFHJ

What I want to do that : https://ibb.co/RvM48rn

How can I do that? What file should I use? (CSS or JS)

```html
<section id="portfolio-details" class="portfolio-details">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row gy-4">

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="portfolio-details-slider swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper align-items-center">

            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/projects-concept-black-chalkboard-d-rendering-handwritten-top-view-office-desk-lot-business-office-supplies-79906734.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/projects-concept-black-chalkboard-d-rendering-handwritten-top-view-office-desk-lot-business-office-supplies-79906734.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/projects-concept-black-chalkboard-d-rendering-handwritten-top-view-office-desk-lot-business-office-supplies-79906734.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="portfolio-info">
          <h3>Project information</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><strong>Category</strong>: Web design</li>
            <li><strong>Customer</strong>: ASU Company</li>
            <li><strong>Project Date</strong>: 01 March, 2020</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-description">
          <h2>Project Title</h2>
          <p>
            Autem ipsum nam porro corporis rerum. Quis eos dolorem eos itaque inventore commodi labore quia quia. Exercitationem repudiandae officiis neque suscipit non officia eaque itaque enim. Voluptatem officia accusantium nesciunt est omnis tempora consectetur
            dignissimos. Sequi nulla at esse enim cum deserunt eius.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "text is passed by Image". And could you edit your live snippet to contain the images you are talking about. E.g. by changing the images url from `/Content/SiteLayout/assets/img/...` to some image url on the web.
I am not sure what problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: @dannymo I edit my post. There is a problem in `<p>`. How can I display other text after the text part is passed by Image's height.

Comment: @dannymo How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I will try to answer quicker from now on.
Your snippet is not working because it has no styles so I cannot see the problem there. But if I understand correctly your problem based on the images, it may be caused by the fact that all the text is in a block element `<div class="col-lg-6">` If this element is ment to be on the right side of the first `<div class="col-lg-6">` then everything in it will be also on the right. If you want the text to go to the left, try using floating. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp Or fix the snippet so we can edit the code

Comment: @dannymo I cannot fix my issue.